# Importing an image causes paintComponent to not start

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, paintcomponent

I have two classes in my project, Client and Card. When I try to import an image into the Card class, the paintComponent method in the client does not start. The timer still fires, and and outputs after repaint in the timer listener still print. The cause of this problem appears to be the try catch in the constructor of the card.

```
package card;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Card {
    BufferedImage cardImage;
    Point loc = new Point(50, 50);
    int scale = 1;

    public Card(){
        try {
            cardImage = ImageIO.read(new File("Penguins.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2){
        g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        if(cardImage == null)
            g2.fillRect(loc.x, loc.y, 150, 225);
        else
            g2.drawImage(cardImage, loc.x, loc.y, 50, 150, null);
    }
}
```

New class

```
package core;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import card.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Client extends JPanel {

    ArrayList<Card>[] board;
    Card card;
    Timer timer;
    static Client player;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Game");
        window.setSize(1080, 720);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setLocation(50, 50);
        window.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        player = new Client();
        window.setContentPane(player);
    }

    public Client() {
        //board = new ArrayList<Card>[4];
        card = new Card();
        ActionListener game = new TimerListener();
        timer = new Timer(100, game);
        timer.start();
    }

    public class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        g2.drawOval(15, 75, 200, 200);
        g2.drawOval(15, 350, 200, 200);
        g2.drawRoundRect(355, -10, 450, 60, 15, 15);
        g2.drawRoundRect(230, 75, 700, 90, 20, 20);
        g2.drawRoundRect(230, 190, 700, 90, 20, 20);
        g2.drawRoundRect(230, 350, 700, 90, 20, 20);
        g2.drawRoundRect(230, 475, 700, 90, 20, 20);
        g2.drawRoundRect(355, 590, 450, 90, 15, 15);
        g2.drawRoundRect(950, 75, 90, 90, 10, 10);
        g2.drawRoundRect(950, 190, 90, 90, 10, 10);
        g2.drawRoundRect(950, 350, 90, 90, 10, 10);
        g2.drawRoundRect(950, 475, 90, 90, 10, 10);
        card.draw(g2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the image stored? Is there any exception thrown?

Comment: Aren't you suppose to run the `Swing` application on [Event Dispatcher Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), learn about __Initial Threads__ from the link. A bit about how to [add images to Java Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), has been added to this post. I hope it will be helpful :-)

Comment: +1 to MadProgrammer. Can you please confirm where the image is stored.

Comment: FYI- With my own image, your code works

Comment: With MadProgrammer's testing, (based in the path you're using - which is only the file name), I can then say your image file needs to be in the root of the working directory (if being run from your IDE), which is the root of the project. When reading a File, the search will begin from the working directory. Also see nIcEcOw's link for adding images to projects. It may be that you want to embedd the image to your program, in which case, reading from a File is insufficient, and should instead be read from an url